# Двойной амперсанд (первое объявление амперсанда в параметрах функции, второе - перед использованием)

Tags: c++11

Не могу понять, что означает запись `(char*)&info` из этого блока кода

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, MyClass &info)
{
    out.writeRawData((char*)&info, sizeof(info));
    return out;
}
```

Эта запись превращает `&info` в `&&info`? Или здесь идёт совсем другая логика? 
Спасибо за любую помощь.
P.S. Общий смысл функции понятен, но нюанс двойного амперсанда - нет (вернее, происходит ли трансформация в двойной?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В списке аргументов амперсанд означает, что в функцию аргумент передаётся с помощью адреса в памяти, и в программе ипользуется именно текущее состояние памяти. Внутри программы амперсанд возвращает именно этот адрес.
**(char*)&info** это грубый намёк компилятору, что указатель **&info** указывает не на  объект **PbxCfgHeader** , а на участок памяти с байтами типа **char**.

Answer (score 1):

Происходит тут вот что:
Параметр в функцию приходит по ссылке (причем криво, надо бы по константной ссылке).

То есть, у нас info - это сам PbxCfgHeader.

Теперь разбираем, что происходит в `(char*)&info`. А происходит тут страшное - мы берем указатель на `info` - это будет `&info`, после чего насильно говорим компилятору считать его указателем на `char`. Делаем мы это для того, чтобы далее иметь право вызвать `writeRawData`, потому как она ожидает первым параметром тип `char*`.

Причем приведение типов здесь сделано "как в C", что неправильно, потому как в C++ есть свой способ:

```
out.writeRawData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&info), sizeof(info));
```

Он более многословен, зато яснее.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. И за советы, буду их придерживаться.

Answer (score 0):

Запишите

```
PbxCfgHeader &info
```

как

```
PbxCfgHeader& info
```

Т.е. `info` - ссылка на `PbxCfgHeader`. Так понятнее? :)

А взятие `&info` - это просто адрес переменной, на которую указывает ссылка...

Comment: Т.е. мы берём адрес, который указывает на адрес? 
Если так, то понял, большое спасибо)